# Symfony4. How to modify login data before login?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I want to change login data like this: `$username = trim(strtolower($username));`

For it, I have created the LoginSubscriber. The method onKernelRequest is called before login, but how can I modify there the data? 
Maybe there are another ways to do it?

```
class LoginSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        dd($event->getRequest()->request->get('username'));
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 9]
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your `LoginSubscriber`:

```
class LoginSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ($request->request->has('username')) {
             $username = trim(strtolower($request->request->get('username')));
             // Update the username request value
             $request->request->set('username', $username);
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 9]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not, what I need. I want to change the data BEFORE login. If I don't do that, the login is often impossible. (Because of case sensitive and spaces).
And I don't need to save the changed data.

Comment: It can't work. `$request` is only a variable within the function onKernelRequest. Setting of $request takes no effect to the login process

Comment: The `$request` is an object, exists throughout the life cycle of each request call on symfony application. In your case, we make an update to the object itself, you can check the new value by capturing the request object on a controller. It should be updated.

Comment: anyway it doesn't work. I can log in with foo, but not with FOO

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set higher priority `priority: 200`for listed request listener, in services.yml config file? Try to bin/console debug:event-dispatcher command to see execution queue

Comment: No, I didn't. For what?

Comment: For you request listener

Comment: For which purpose do I need to set the higher priority?

Comment: @olek07 Purpose is maybe you can modify data before login process fires

Comment: I don't know *HOW* to modify the data. There is no `return` in the function

Comment: Try to use data transformer inside your login form type https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: I'm using no custom login form.